# Как отправить пользовательский ввод в базу данных?

Tags: php, javascript

Я вывожу название кнопок из базы данных. Потом через javascript генерирую в древо кнопок. Мне нужно чтобы при окончание цикла появилось форма для инпута. Еще, чтобы все нажатые кнопки отправились в бд.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["id"])){
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("test", $db);
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Buttons` WHERE `parent` = $id");
    $buttons = array();
    while($button = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($buttons, array($button["id"], $button["parent"], $button["value"]));
    }
    echo json_encode($buttons);
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Buttons tree</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12 main" id="field">
            <h1>Buttons tree</h1>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <p>Root buttons</p>
                <div id="rootButtons">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.post("/buttons.php", {id: 0}, function(e){
            var buttons = $.parseJSON(e);
            $.each(buttons, function(key, value){
                $("#rootButtons").append("<button class='btn btn-danger' id='parent' idb='"+value[0]+"'>"+value[2]+"</button>");
            })
        })
    //Click on parent
    $(document).on("click","#parent", function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        var idb = $(this).attr("idb")
        $.post("/buttons.php", {id: idb}, function(data){
            var buttons = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#field").append("<div class='jumbotron' id='buttons"+idb+"'><p>Childs for "+obj.html()+" ("+idb+")</p></div>");
            $.each(buttons, function(key, value){
                $("#buttons"+idb).append("<button class='btn btn-success' id='parent' idb='"+value[0]+"'>"+value[2]+"</button>");
            })
        })
    })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы на превьюшку смотрели перед тем, как отправить вопрос? Почему нет?

Comment: Что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: мне нужно когда закончится древно кнопок появилось форма для инпута